# плавный скролл jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать автоматический плавный скрол до определенного блока? 
Допустим зашел на страницу, и через 5 секунд проскролило до определенного блока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var top = $(element).offset().top;
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
    }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z23f415d/1/)